# how to Loop through mulltiple fieldsets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, fieldset

I have this function to append to my form (which is a modal window):

```
function appendAddressForm(name, line1, line2, phone, fax) {
    $("#addressForm form").append(
        "<div style='clear:both;text-align:left;padding:10;'>" +        
        "<fieldset style='width:70%;padding:5;float:left'>" +
        "<ul class='ui-helper-clearfix'>" +
            "<li class='ui-state-default ui-corner-all' title='Delete Address' id><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minus'></span></li>" +               
        "</ul>" +           
        "<label for='addressName'  style='width:100px'>Office Name</label>" +
        "<input type='text' size='20' name='addressName' id='addressName' value='" +  name + "' /> <br>" +
        "<label for='addressOne'  style='width:100px'>Address Line 1</label>" +
        "<input type='text' size='40' name='addressOne' id='addressOne' value='" +  line1 + "' /> <br>" +
        "<label for='addressTwo'  style='width:100px'>Address Line 2</label>" +
        "<input type='text' size='40' name='addressTwo' id='addressTwo' value='" +  line2 + "'/> <br>" +
        "<label for='addressPhone'  style='width:100px'>Phone</label>" +
        "<input type='text' size='20' name='addressPhone' id='addressPhone' value='(P)" +  phone + "' /> <br>" +
        "<label for='addressFax'  style='width:100px'>Fax</label>" +
        "<input type='text' size='20' name='addressFax' id='addressFax' value='(F)" +  fax + "' />" +   
    "</fieldset>" +             
"</div>");
}
```

this is how i am accessing first field set

```
var addressName = $.trim($("#addressName").val());
var addressOne = $.trim($("#addressOne").val());
var addressTwo = $.trim($("#addressTwo").val());
var addressPhone = $.trim($("#addressPhone").val());
var addressFax = $.trim($("#addressFax").val());
```

if(addressName != "" && addressOne != "" && addressPhone != "(P)" && addressFax != "(F)")

{

I have jQuery, and a button.  Upon click of this button I have to append a section which contains this fieldset.  I can add up to 6 fieldsets to my form.  My problem is, I am able to get only values of first field set.  I want to validate all other fieldsets too.  How can I get the values from other field sets?

Comment: When you say "get the values", do you mean on the server side using PHP, or on the client side using JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all of your inputs have the same name attributes and id's, add another variable to your `appendAddressForm(name, line1, line2, phone, fax, number)` in  this case I have added `number`. Add this variable to your id's and name attributes i.e:

```
<input type='text' size='20' name='addressName-"+number+"' id='addressName-"+number+"' value='" +  name + "' />
```

Comment: I am dynamically appending the above fieldset so it should be like that only.